# How can I create and loop through a custom array within a react functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the case of my FAQ (frequently asked questions) page I have a `function` that repeats the same text 9 times and I am unable to individually customize each row's question and answer.

Can someone please explain how I can refactor this code so that I can `add`/`edit` my own custom rows with a question and answer format?

You will notice that each question is a clickable row that reveals the answer to each question (see image).

Thank you!

[image]

```
import { useState } from "react"
import "./FaqPage.scss"

export default function FaqPage() {
  const [faqRow, setfaqRow] = useState(0)
  const faqToggle = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    setfaqRow(data)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <section className="innerBAnner">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
              <h1>Frequently asked questions</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section className="aboutPage">
        <div className="aboutLayerTwo">
          <div className="container">
            <figure className="mb-xl-5 mb-xl-5">
              <img src="img/img13.png" alt="" className="w-100 d-block" />
            </figure>
            <div className="row align-items-center pt-md-5"></div>
            <div className="row">
              {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].map((data, ind) => (
                <div className="col-md-12">
                  <div className="faq-row">
                    <div
                      className="d-flex align-items-end  faq-head"
                      onClick={() => faqToggle(ind)}
                    >
                      <b>0{ind + 1}</b>
                      <h4 className="me-auto">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing?
                      </h4>
                      <span>
                        {faqRow === ind ? (
                          <svg
                            width="19"
                            height="30"
                            viewBox="0 0 19 30"
                            fill="none"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                          >
                            <path
                              d="M18.1189 14.6937L16.4545 12.95L4.40707 0.268555L0.731445 3.75596L11.1243 14.6937L0.731445 25.6315L4.40707 29.1189L16.4545 16.4374L18.1189 14.6937Z"
                              fill="#353535"
                            />
                          </svg>
                        ) : (
                          <svg
                            width="29"
                            height="18"
                            viewBox="0 0 29 18"
                            fill="none"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                          >
                            <path
                              d="M14.4254 17.3875L16.1691 15.723L28.8506 3.67563L25.3632 -1.52439e-07L14.4254 10.3928L3.48764 -1.10865e-06L0.000232541 3.67563L12.6817 15.723L14.4254 17.3875Z"
                              fill="#353535"
                            />
                          </svg>
                        )}
                      </span>
                    </div>
                    {faqRow === ind && (
                      <div className="faq-body">
                        <p>
                          XXXXX Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing
                          and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                          industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
                          when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                          scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
                          survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                          into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                          unchanged.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
                          typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                          industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
                          when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                          scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you already know JS you can pick up React via e.g. https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html. Note you want to _change_ the behaviour, this is strictly not refactoring.

Comment: Put the Q&A in an array of objects w/ `q` and `a` properties. Map over that like the current array of numbers are. Display the `q` and `a` properties of each object where the lorem text is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an array which looks like this:

```
const faqArray = [{question: 'What is my question', answer: 'this is my answer'}, {question: 'What is another question', answer: 'this is another answer'}]
```

This is your new FAQ array which stores your questions and answers. Place it in your file under `import "./FaqPage.scss"`

```
import { useState } from "react"
import "./FaqPage.scss"

const faqArray = [{question: 'What is my question', answer: 'this is my answer'}, {question: 'What is another question', answer: 'this is another answer'}]
```

Next go to where it has the following:

`{[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].map`

and replace the `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` with
`{faqArray.map` This is allowing your React component to `loop` over the contents in the new array that we just made.

then where it says

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing?
```

replace it with `{data.question}` This is replacing Lorem ipsum with your question that was stored in your FAQ array above.

Then where it has the paragraphs replace the paragraphs with `<p>{data.answer}</p>` This is taking the answer you placed in your FAQ array and displaying it here. **Note** this will all be placed within one paragraph tag, if you want multiple paragraph tags it will take more complicated code. I would suggest this for now.

Now whenever you want to add a new question just add it to the faqArray like this `{question: 'New question', answer: 'New answer'}` the `question:`  and  `answer:`  are required as keys. don't change them unless you know what you are doing.

so with this new question it would look like this:

```
const faqArray = [{question: 'What is my question', answer: 'this is my answer'}, {question: 'What is another question', answer: 'this is another answer'}, {question: 'New question', answer: 'New answer'}]
```

After all is said and done your component should look like this:

```
import { useState } from "react"
import "./FaqPage.scss"

const faqArray = [{question: 'What is my question', answer: 'this is my answer'}, {question: 'What is another question', answer: 'this is another answer'}]

export default function FaqPage() {
  const [faqRow, setfaqRow] = useState(0)
  const faqToggle = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    setfaqRow(data)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <section className="innerBAnner">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-12">
              <h1>Frequently asked questions</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section className="aboutPage">
        <div className="aboutLayerTwo">
          <div className="container">
            <figure className="mb-xl-5 mb-xl-5">
              <img src="img/img13.png" alt="" className="w-100 d-block" />
            </figure>
            <div className="row align-items-center pt-md-5"></div>
            <div className="row">
              {faqArray.map((data, ind) => (
                <div className="col-md-12">
                  <div className="faq-row">
                    <div
                      className="d-flex align-items-end  faq-head"
                      onClick={() => faqToggle(ind)}
                    >
                      <b>0{ind + 1}</b>
                      <h4 className="me-auto">
                        {data.question}
                      </h4>
                      <span>
                        {faqRow === ind ? (
                          <svg
                            width="19"
                            height="30"
                            viewBox="0 0 19 30"
                            fill="none"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                          >
                            <path
                              d="M18.1189 14.6937L16.4545 12.95L4.40707 0.268555L0.731445 3.75596L11.1243 14.6937L0.731445 25.6315L4.40707 29.1189L16.4545 16.4374L18.1189 14.6937Z"
                              fill="#353535"
                            />
                          </svg>
                        ) : (
                          <svg
                            width="29"
                            height="18"
                            viewBox="0 0 29 18"
                            fill="none"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                          >
                            <path
                              d="M14.4254 17.3875L16.1691 15.723L28.8506 3.67563L25.3632 -1.52439e-07L14.4254 10.3928L3.48764 -1.10865e-06L0.000232541 3.67563L12.6817 15.723L14.4254 17.3875Z"
                              fill="#353535"
                            />
                          </svg>
                        )}
                      </span>
                    </div>
                    {faqRow === ind && (
                      <div className="faq-body">
                        <p>
                          {data.answer}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  )
}
```